# SVG MOVES ON to the next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

The first SVG (Done) is after the button. When the button is clicked, a second SVG with 2 check marks (Done All) is supposed to come up. It happens, but it appears below the 1ˢᵗ instead of next to. SO basically it goes to the next line. How can I prevent this?

There is CSS added in for SVG display confirmation.

```js
const firstSVG =
document.getElementsByClassName("firstSVG");
const secondSVG =
document.getElementsByClassName("secondSVG");

function show() {
  secondSVG[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
svg[id="first"] {
  display: block;
}
svg[id="second"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Show second SVG</button>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000" class="firstSVG" id="first"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000" style="display: none;" class="secondSVG" id="second"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M18 7l-1.41-1.41-6.34 6.34 1.41 1.41L18 7zm4.24-1.41L11.66 16.17 7.48 12l-1.41 1.41L11.66 19l12-12-1.42-1.41zM.41 13.41L6 19l1.41-1.41L1.83 12 .41 13.41z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display: inline; (or inline-block) rather than display: block;

```js
const firstSVG =
document.getElementsByClassName("firstSVG");
const secondSVG =
document.getElementsByClassName("secondSVG");

function show() {
  secondSVG[0].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
svg[id="first"] {
  display: inline;
}
svg[id="second"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show()">Show second SVG</button>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000" class="firstSVG" id="first"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"/></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000" style="display: none;" class="secondSVG" id="second"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M18 7l-1.41-1.41-6.34 6.34 1.41 1.41L18 7zm4.24-1.41L11.66 16.17 7.48 12l-1.41 1.41L11.66 19l12-12-1.42-1.41zM.41 13.41L6 19l1.41-1.41L1.83 12 .41 13.41z"/></svg>
```

Comment: For positioning ``display:inline-block`` could be better: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp